# Defining Docker runtime flags from within Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

We're running Docker on Digital Ocean App Engine, and can't pass flags (e.g. `--cpus`) to `docker run`.

We can't use `docker-compose` either.

Is it possible to set an environment variable (`ARG`? `ENV`?), e.g. `$CPUS=blah`) in a way that can be picked up by the Docker instance?

Stated differently, are there internal environment variables that correspond to specific flags, that can be set from with a Dockerfile / environment itself?

Comment: Nope. It's part of Docker's security model that things that impact the runtime environment (port mapping, resource limits, etc) can only be specified *external* to images.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in the very first steps of official documentation of Docker ([this link](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/)):

> Docker provides the ability to package and run an application in a loosely isolated environment called a container. The isolation and security allow you to run many containers simultaneously on a given host. Containers are lightweight and contain everything needed to run the application, so you do not need to rely on what is currently installed on the host. You can easily share containers while you work, and be sure that everyone you share with gets the same container that works in the same way.

The main concept of Docker is to ***isolate*** each container from the other container, environment variables and anything that relates to the them. So the only thing we can access and modify them is what that reside outside of the container like:

- exposing ports
- exposing volumes
- map container port to the host port
- map container volume to the host volume and vice-versa
- ...